# How do I get the name of a socket option in C?

Tags: c, networking, libc

I have some code that looks like this:

```c
    switch (option) {
        case MVM_SO_BROADCAST:
        case MVM_SO_KEEPALIVE:
        case MVM_SO_REUSEADDR:
        case MVM_SO_DONTROUTE:
        case MVM_SO_SNDBUF:
        case MVM_SO_RCVBUF:
        case MVM_SO_OOBINLINE:
        case MVM_TCP_NODELAY: {
            int input;
            len = sizeof(int);
            e = getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, (int)option, (char *)&input, &len);
            output = input;
            break;
        }
        case MVM_SO_LINGER: {
            struct linger input;
            len = sizeof(struct linger);
            e = getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, (int)option, (char *)&input, &len);
            // Match Java's behaviour with SO_LINGER
            output = (input.l_onoff >= 0) ? input.l_linger : -1;
            break;
        }
        default:
            MVM_exception_throw_adhoc(tc, "this socket option is not supported by MoarVM: %d", (int)option);
            break;
    }
```

`MVM_SO_BROADCAST` and the like are macros for `SO_BROADCAST` and the like. In the default case in the switch, I want to print the name of the socket option given instead of its value, which is useless to the end user. Is there a function in libc for this?

Comment: There is no libc function for this. You will have to write your own.

Comment: when calling `getsockopt()`, and it returns a 'active' indication, then call `printf()` with the name, etc to `stdout`.  This hints at each case in the posted code will have a different content for the `printf()` so should be  each each case